# JUnit assumptions fail Theories

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I was messing arround with JUnit `@Theory` and find out that `assumeTrue(false)` fails the theory instrad if ignore it.

This code fail the test:

```
@RunWith(Theories.class)
public class SnippetTest {

   @Theory
   public void validateIndices(){
       assumeTrue(false);
   }
}
```

> SnippetTest.validateIndices Never found parameters that satisfied
>   method assumptions.  Violated assumptions:
>   [org.junit.AssumptionViolatedException: got: false, expected: is
>   true]

But when I'm using @Test assumption ignore it.

```
public class SnippetTest {

    @Test
    public void validateIndices() {
        assumeTrue(false);
    }
}
```

It's contraversial with [Theories Documentation](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/experimental/theories/Theories.html).

> If any of the assumptions fail, the data point is silently ignored.

What am I missing or what am doing wrong?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the *data point* is ignored, not the theory. Looks like this behavior is fine.

Comment: You are totaly right. Thak you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @TamasRev comment I found what was going wrong. Looks like, it will fail the test in case all the the assumption fails. Im the case I posted, I have only one assumption.
What is happening if I'm using `@DataPoints`?
This one fails as well

```
@RunWith(Theories.class)
public class SnippetTest {

    @DataPoints
    public static boolean[] data(){
        return new boolean[]{false, false};
    }

   @Theory
   public void validateIndices(boolean data){
       assumeTrue(data);
       assertTrue(true);
   }
}
```

But when if at least one assumption pass then test is not failed.

```
@RunWith(Theories.class)
public class SnippetTest {

    @DataPoints
    public static boolean[] data(){
        return new boolean[]{false, true};
    }

   @Theory
   public void validateIndices(boolean data){
       assumeTrue(data);
       assertTrue(true);
   }
}
```

Thanx @TamasRev for pointing me to right direction.